# Remove Duplicate Items in Dictionary

Tags: python, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicate items in a list through a dictionary:

```
def RemoveDuplicates(list):
    d = dict()

    for i in xrange(0, len(list)):
        dict[list[i]] = 1       <------- error here

    return d.keys()
```

But it is raising me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Variable names like `dict` and `list` are a Very Bad Idea.  Never call a variable `dict`, `list`, `tuple`, `int`, `float` or anything of the kind.  It makes it very hard to discern what you're talking about.  And it may make your program not work because your local variable name has replaced a built-in name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should have written:

```
d[list[i]] = 1
```

But why not do this?

```
def RemoveDuplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))
```

Also, don't use built-in function names as variable names. It can lead to confusing bugs.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what others have said, it is unpythonic to do this:

```
for i in xrange(0, len(lst)):
    do stuff with lst[i]
```

when you can do this instead:

```
for item in lst:
    do stuff with item
```

Answer (score 3):

dict is the type, you mean `d[list[i]] = 1`.

Addition:  This points out the actual error in your code.  But the answers provided by others provide better way to achieve what you are aiming at.

Answer (score 3):

```
def remove_duplicates(myList):
    return list (set(myList))
```

From looking at your code it seems that you are not bothered about the ordering of elements and concerned only about the uniqueness. In such a case, a set() could be a better data structure.

The problem in your code is just to use a function argument name which is not the name of the built-in type list and later on the type dict in the expression `dict[list[i]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using `list(set(seq))` will likely change the ordering of the remaining items.  If retaining their order is important, you need to make a copy of the list:

```
items = set()
copy = []
for item in seq:
    if not item in items:
        copy.add(item)
        items.append(item)
seq = copy
```